# Save and re-stream RSTP video as straight UDP

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, boost-asio, rtsp

I am trying to write a program that will connect to a RTSP video source and redirect the video data to another location using UDP. I am also saving the RTSP packets to be able to replay the video stream at a latter moment in time as well. Right now my program can connect to the RTSP video stream and redirect and save, but when I try to look at the redirected video I get nothing using VLC.

Currently the program just strips out the datagram from the RTSP video packets it receives in its open UDP socket and re-sends them using this code using the boost asio library.

```
newVideoSocket->send_to(&dg.data[0], dg.data.size() ,Endpoint);
```

When I look at the traffic using Wireshark I see that it is actually sending the data to the new address and it is recognized as a UDP packet, but when I try and view the video using VLC nothing happens. The video stream is Mpeg4 with the video encoded as H.264 and VLC can play it.

I have tried to connect to the redirected stream as UDP and as RTP at both multicast and unicast addresses but have had no success. Do I need to add or take something out of the datagram before I resend it? Or is it something wrong with how I am tring to view it in VLC? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure VLC is able to play "raw" UDP packets? Usually one needs some higher-level protocol like RTP.

Answer (score 0):

To play raw UDP-stream VLC needs information about a stream (this information is transferred through RTSP in DESCRIBE and SETUP messages). Try to create sdp file, specifying port number, video type, etc (you need to read DESCRIBE response from serer) and then open it in vlc.

I've managed to make it work, but using VLC like this I've encountered problems with synchronization and video output (video was broken).